# Show that random sum of ergodic processes is not ergodic

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, asymptotics, self-learning, ergodic-theory

We say that a mean stationary stochastic process $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb N}$ - i.e. $E[X_t]= \mu_X$ for all $t$ -  is ergodic mean if
\begin{equation}\tag{I}
\frac 1 T \sum_{t=1}^T X_t  \overset {pr} \longrightarrow \mu_X, \quad (T \to \infty)
\end{equation}
It staightforward to show that the finite sum of ergodic processes is ergodic:  Let $(X_{t;j})_{1\leq j \leq n}$ be a finite sequence of ergodic process and $Y_{t;n} = \sum_{j=1}^n X_{t;j}$. So:
$$\frac 1 T \sum_{t=1}^T Y_{t;n}  \overset {pr} \longrightarrow \mu_n, \quad (T \to \infty)$$
where $\mu_j= E[X_{t;j}]$ and $\mu_n = \sum_{j=1}^n \mu_j$.

But, how about a random sum?

More specifically, Let $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb N}$ be a ergodic process with $\mu_X = E[X_t]$ as **(I)** above.  Consider
$$Y_t = \sum_{j=1}^N X_{t;j}, \quad N\sim \hbox {Poisson} (\lambda)$$
where $X_{t,1}, X_{t,2},..., X_{t,j},...  \overset {\mathrm{i.i.d}} \sim  X_{t}$ for all $t$ (copies) and independent of $N$.

Note that this process is not the Compound Poisson Process. This is just a stationary process such that $Y_t$ is a Compound Poisson random variable, for all $t$, according with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution).

It straightforward to show that $(Y_t)_{t\in \mathbb N}$ is mean stationary
$$E[Y_t]= \lambda \mu_X, \quad \forall\, t \in \mathbb N.$$

How to show that

\begin{equation}%\tag{I}
\frac 1 T \sum_{t=1}^T Y_t  \overset {pr} \longrightarrow \lambda \mu_X, \quad (T \to \infty) \quad ??
\end{equation}
My first attempt is try to show that $P\left(\left| \frac 1 T \sum_{t=1}^T Y_t - \lambda \mu_X \right| > \epsilon \right) \to 0$, as $T \to \infty$, for all $\epsilon >0$. Note:
\begin{aligned}
P\left(\left| \frac 1 T \sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{j=1}^N X_{t;j}, - \lambda \mu_X \right| > \epsilon \right) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty P\left(\left| \frac 1 T \sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{j=1}^n X_{t;j} - \lambda \mu_X \right| > \epsilon \right)P(N=n)\\
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty& P\left(\left| \frac 1 T \sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{j=1}^n X_{t;j} - n \mu_X + n \mu_X + \lambda \mu_X \right| > \epsilon \right)P(N=n)
\end{aligned}
So. I am trying to use the ergodicity of $ \sum_{j=1}^n X_{t;j}$, i.e.: $P\left(\left| \frac 1 T \sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{j=1}^n X_{t;j} - n \mu_X  \right| > \epsilon \right)  \overset {pr} \longrightarrow 0$ as $T \to \infty$.

How to conclude?  Is there another way to show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can show that
$$
\frac 1T\sum_{t=1}^T\sum_{j=1}^NX_{t;j}-N\mu_X\to 0\mbox{ in probability as }T\to\infty.
$$
Indeed, proceeding similarly as in the opening post,
$$
\mathbb P\left(\left| \frac 1 T \sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{j=1}^N X_{t;j}, -N\mu_X \right| > \epsilon \right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb  P\left(\left| \frac 1 T \sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{j=1}^n X_{t;j} - n\mu_X \right| > \epsilon \right)\mathbb  P(N=n)\\
\leqslant  \sum_{n=1}^R \mathbb  P\left(\left| \frac 1 T \sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{j=1}^n X_{t;j} - n\mu_X \right| > \epsilon \right)+\mathbb P(N\geqslant R+1)
$$
hence by mean-ergodicity of $(X_{t;j})_t$,
$$
\limsup_{T\to\infty}
\mathbb P\left(\left| \frac 1 T \sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{j=1}^N X_{t;j}, -N\mu_X \right| > \epsilon \right) \leqslant \mathbb P(N\geqslant R+1)
$$
and since $R$ is arbitrary, the conclusion follows.

Comment: I really liked the answer. So $(Y_t)$ is not ergodic? My intuition failed!

Comment: Indeed, unless $\mu_X=1$, $(Y_t)$ is not mean-ergodic.

Comment: I meant $\mu_X=0$.